# Can't Reinstall Curl on Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, curl, osx-snow-leopard

I was trying to install homebrew, and when it didn't work I tried deleting curl, and I can't find anything that can help me with reinstalling curl.

After I make it, I try putting the resulting curl unix executable back where (I think). the original was, but when I try using curl it says:curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 400.

Here's a log:http://pastebin.com/SuHPvxym

Thanks.

P.S. I deleted curl from /usr/bin or something like that.

Comment: curl comes with MAC OS X since years, so if you have deleted curl you need to reinstall SL or get the binary from someone who also have SL.

Comment: I can't reinstall I got this mac refurbished and this is the only mac I have.

Comment: I´m not sure but i think SL was the first Version who was able to be reinstalled via Web. But if not you could download the image e.g. here: http://en.softonic.com/s/mac-os-x-snow-leopard-10.6-full-version:mac

Comment: Softonic contains lots of viruses, have you downloaded that file from there before?

Comment: No i just googled for downloading SL